# How do generics implement structs?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, cil

I was thinking about this. classes are obviously passed around by ptr. I suspect structs are passed around by copying it but i don't know for sure. (it seems like a waste for an int array to have every element a ptr. and passing ptrs for ints)

But thinking about it, `List<MyStruct>` can not know the size of my struct. What happens when i do this? Are there multiple copies of "List`1" and every time i use it with a storage size it does not have it creates a new implementation? (adjusting for the new offsets of T and such).

That could make sense since the source would be in the CIL inside of a DLL. But i am completely guessing, how is it done? Perhaps a reference or page # to the ECMA standards?

Comment: I know little about how C# implements generics.  But for reference, that's exactly how C++ templates work (in theory, a separate implementation of `List` would be instantiated for each type).

Comment: @Oli: yep, also i know it doesnt compile methods unless you use it and you need the template in the header. C# doesnt have headers but generics still work after they been compiled into a dll

Comment: @Oli: That is, it will have separate implementations for each value type and one shared implementation for reference types.

Comment: @Oded: I dont see how your links answer anything... Neither of them mention generics

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generics use the concept of open and closed generic types: A parametrized generic class definition (i.e. `List<T>`) is an open generic type of which the runtime generates a closed generic type for each different use you have in your code, i.e. a different type is created for `List<int>` and for `List<MyStruct>` - for each closed generic type the size and type of `T` is known at run-time.

Clarification from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx):

> When a generic type or method is
>   compiled into Microsoft intermediate
>   language (MSIL), it contains metadata
>   that identifies it as having type
>   parameters. How the MSIL for a generic
>   type is used differs based on whether
>   the supplied type parameter is a value
>   type or reference type.
>
> When a generic type is first
>   constructed with a value type as a
>   parameter, the runtime creates a
>   specialized generic type with the
>   supplied parameter or parameters
>   substituted in the appropriate
>   locations in the MSIL. Specialized
>   generic types are created one time for
>   each unique value type that is used as
>   a parameter.
>
> Generics work somewhat differently for
>   reference types. The first time a
>   generic type is constructed with any
>   reference type, the runtime creates a
>   specialized generic type with object
>   references substituted for the
>   parameters in the MSIL. Then, every
>   time that a constructed type is
>   instantiated with a reference type as
>   its parameter, regardless of what type
>   it is, the runtime reuses the
>   previously created specialized version
>   of the generic type. This is possible
>   because all references are the same
>   size.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR compiles 1 version of the generic class and uses it for all reference types. It also compiles 1 version for every value type usage to optimize for performance.